# Using Google Sign In to authenticate using PHP. What should I do with emails that have the domain @pages.plusgoogle.com?

Tags: php, google-plus, youtube-data-api

So I'm trying to retrieve the email address from Google in order to make it easy for users to create accounts on the service I'm building. I currently have two accounts associated with youtube under one Google account. One of the accounts actually end with my actual email address that ends with @gmail.com. The other one ends with @pages.plusgoogle.com.

If this was a use case, the user would be able to create an account using the email address ending with @page.plusgoogle.com but you can not send emails to that domain. When I tested it, it failed to send an email address to that domain.

I don't want to save an email address into my service with an email address that doesn't work. How would I verify that the user is human if I can't verify their email address? What should I do in this case?

Comment: Just do a simple `strpos` for that subdomain and exclude it

Comment: No no no. The email address is valid. But won't work. I can't send an email to the email address because it doesn't exist. I don't want to store non-existent email addresses into my service. You are misunderstanding the problem. This isn't a duplicate. The email is valid but you can't send emails to it.

Comment: Come on man. I don't want repost this.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my previous comment? There's nothing new about this question

Comment: I don't have a choice to choose between the two (or maybe numerous) emails. The user chooses the email to give to me. Are you saying remove @pages.plusgoogle.com myself and add in @gmail.com?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. Either exclude them with `strpos` or just replace it with `str_replace` (although the latter may not work in assuming it's always going to be Gmail)

Comment: Alright, nevermind then. Thanks.